# Cannot create listitem REST API in SP 2013 with contributes rights

Tags: 2013, permissions, rest

I have an issue with our Travel Tool based on SharePoint 2013. This tool consists of different Content Types - all in their specific lists (travel requests, train rides, flights, etc.). There are two main groups which are using this tool: **Employees** (contribute) and **admin** staff (full control).
On the **homepage.aspx** we have a **ScriptEditorWebpart** with a custom **HomePageNewItem** button and a **ListView** of the travel requests. When the user clicks on the custom button, a new ListItem is created via REST API and the **EditForm.aspx** of the currently created ListItem is displayed.

What is the problem?

This works just fine for the admin staff (full control). When employees try to create a ListItem, the following error message occurs: `HRESULT: 0x80131904` (returning from the REST API). The same happens, when employees visit some of the lists. The ListView isn’t displayed, but there is the same error message.

Some additional information:

- The SQL database has enough storage on all partitions
- When an employee uses the standard “New Item” Button, everything works just fine (except of the ListView)
- When an employee is moved to the admin staff group, everything works just fine
- All lists have correct permissions set
- This worked one week before and there were no changes in the code, only some customizations of sites e.g. homepage.aspx)

Additional hints:

Could it has something to do with the Website Definition?

Comment: If Employees can create items the 'normal' SharePoint way, the problem must be in the script that creates the new item.